# How to read a UILabel through UIButtons (that have no text)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I am trying to see the amount of points (times I have clicked the `UIButtons`) using a `UILabel`, but I can only see the number until a `UIButton` spawns on it.  Even if I click on the `UIButton`, it will "disappear," really just turn black like the `self.view.backgroundColor`, but will still be blocking the `UILabel`'s text from being seen.

Is there any simple solutions to this, or would the best way to be just to not allow squares to spawn there, but then you would not be able to do `enemy.center` for it would be even harder to click.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var points: Int = 0

    func randomPoint() -> CGPoint {
        let randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()%320),y:CGFloat(arc4random()%568))
        return randomPoint
    }

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 150, height: 150))
        enemy.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        enemy.center = randomPoint()
        enemy.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPushed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy)
    }

    func buttonPushed(sender : UIButton) {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        points = points + 1
        scoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        scoreLabel.text = "\(points)"
        scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        if sender.frame.height < 50 || sender.frame.width < 50 {
            sender.frame = CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x, sender.frame.origin.y, 50, 50)
            sender.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
            sender.center = self.randomPoint()
            return
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.75, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the label's zIndex to a higher number so that it's always "in front" of any buttons that may spawn in the exact same spot.  The default is 0, so if you set the label's zIndex to 1 the buttons will spawn underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to see the label when it's behind a button, you could set the `ackgroundColor` to `UIColor.clearColor()` instead of `.blackColor()`

You could also move your `scoreLabel` to a view that is at the top of the screen, and have all your "enemies" spawn in a view below that. You would have to modify `randomPoint()` to take a different size into account, but that might be better than trying to see through your buttons.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you. I did end up modifying randomPoint() and that did work well.